# Getting error: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been getting the following bug on my code:

```
/example.ShopAp( 6215): Background concurrent copying GC freed 34088(1449KB) AllocSpace 
objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 56% free, 1172KB/2708KB, paused 1.011ms total 318.281ms
Restarted application in 9,871ms.
E/SpannableStringBuilder( 6215): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder( 6215): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/flutter ( 6215): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 
'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter ( 6215): #0      ProductsProvider.fetchAndSetProducts 
package:ShopApp/providers/products_provider.dart:95
E/flutter ( 6215): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6215): #1      _ProductsOverviewScreenState.didChangeDependencies 
package:ShopApp/screens/products_overview_screen.dart:43
E/flutter ( 6215): #2      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4661
E/flutter ( 6215): #3      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4476
E/flutter ( 6215): #4      Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3446
E/flutter ( 6215): #5      Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3211
E/flutter ( 6215): #6      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5837
E/flutter ( 6215): #7      Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3201
E/flutter ( 6215): #8      ComponentElement.performRebuild
```

And this is the code down here

```
    import 'package:ShopApp/models/http_exception.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:convert';

    import './products.dart';
```

The code itself

```
    class ProductsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
    List<Product> _items = [
    // Product(
    //   id: 'p1',
    //   title: 'Red Shirt',
    //   description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
    //   price: 16672.14,
    //   imageUrl:
    //       'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    // ),
    // Product(
    //     id: 'p2',
    //     title: 'Kaba Ngondo',
    //     description: 'A beautiful African Kaba Afritude.',
    //     price: 1999,
    //     imageUrl:
    //         
    'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ed/70/39/ed703931a95c6fef3ea08f4ca4f58b55.jpg'),
    // Product(
    //     id: 'p3',
    //     title: 'Afritude school bag',
    //     description: 'Nice Afitude school bags.',
    //     price: 6999,
    //     imageUrl:
    //         
    'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/22/3b/dd/223bdde3a21a3132f84ce1b90ac15881.jpg'),
    // Product(
    //     id: 'p4',
    //     title: 'Traditional shirt',
    //     description: 'Afritude traditional Men\'s shirt',
    //     price: 4999,
    //     



 imageUrl:'https://unseulprix.com/public/uploads/products/thumbnail/PofNHLKT3IWDwKZMhrPQdPykNDT2B5QjHXaVogxn.jpeg'),
      ];

  // var _showFavoritesOnly = false;
  final String authToken;
  final String userId;

  ProductsProvider(this.authToken, this.userId, this._items);

  List<Product> get items {
    // if(_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }
```

Here when I add (`&orderBy='adderId'&equalTo='$userId'`) after $authToken, it bugs, but when I remove, it works like before.

```
 Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
    var url =
        "https://calinshop-e01e0.firebaseio.com/Products.json? 
    auth=$authToken&orderBy='adderId'&equalTo='$userId'";
        

    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
      url =
          "https://calinshop-e01e0.firebaseio.com/userFavorite/$userId.json? 
    auth=$authToken";
      final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
      final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);

      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(
          Product(
            id: prodId,
            title: prodData["title"],
            description: prodData["description"],
            price: prodData["price"],
            imageUrl: prodData["imageUrl"],
            isFavorite:
                favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[prodId] ?? false,
          ),
        );
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
    final url =
        "https://calinshop-e01e0.firebaseio.com/Products.json?auth=$authToken";
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            "title": product.title,
            "description": product.description,
            "imageUrl": product.imageUrl,
            "price": product.price,
            "adderId": userId,
          },
        ),
      );
      final newProduct = Product(
        id: json.decode(response.body)["Name"],
        title: product.title,
        description: product.description,
        imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
        price: product.price,
      );
      _items.add(newProduct);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) async {
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      final url =
          "https://calinshop-e01e0.firebaseio.com/Products/$id.json?auth=$authToken";
      await http.patch(url,
          body: json.encode({
            "title": newProduct.title,
            "description": newProduct.description,
            "price": newProduct.price,
            "imageUrl": newProduct.imageUrl,
          }));
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print("....");
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteProduct(String id) async {
    final url =
        "https://calinshop-e01e0.firebaseio.com/Products/$id.json?auth=$authToken";
    final existingProductIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    var existingProduct = _items[existingProductIndex];

    _items.removeAt(existingProductIndex);
    notifyListeners();
    final response = await http.delete(url);
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      _items.insert(existingProductIndex, existingProduct);
      notifyListeners();
      throw HttpException("Could not delete product");
    }
    existingProduct = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check your `flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)` ? This log `E/flutter ( 6215): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 
'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'` clearly states that  you were trying to pass a `String` to a function or a variable which is of type `int`.

Comment: i'm actually following a tutorial and did exactly what he did but his works mine doesn't